# Echo hidden div content

Tags: php, html, regex

I'm building a little AJAX script, which will get the content of a specified web page and then display the content of the hidden DIV(s), if there is one or more.

The hidden DIV(s) have `style="display:none;"` or `style="display: none;"`, so I want to search for this.

How can I performs this task? I'm not very good with regular expressions :(

I tried with this one, but it doesn't work so far :)

```
$htmldata = file_get_contents($_GET['webaddr']);
$value = preg_match_all('/<div\s*style=\"\s*display:\s*none\s*\">(.*?)<\/div>/s',$htmldata,$estimates);
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Please define "doesn't work".

Comment: Are you sure it always has the `style="display: none;"` and not hidden via external CSS?

Comment: You have forgotten the `;`

Comment: Right now the style isn't in the external CSS.

Comment: probably easier to do this on the client side.

Comment: Parsing HTML with regexp is hardly ever a good idea.

Comment: Post-Output parsing at all is hardly ever a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

I would import the content as a new [DOMDocument](http://php.net/domdocument) and then use the [getAttribute](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domelement.getattribute.php) method to filter for you styles.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this with PHP >= 5.3

```
<?php

$html = <<<'LOD'
<div style="float:right">glups</div>
<div style="display:none;"><span>glaps</span> <br/></div>
<div style="border-top:1px solid red; display: none; float:right;">glops</div>
<div style="display : none">glips</div>
LOD;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$xpath->registerNamespace("php", "http://php.net/xpath");
$xpath->registerPHPFunctions('preg_match');

$divNodes = $xpath->query('//div[php:functionString("preg_match", "~\bdisplay\s*:\s*none\b~i", @style) = 1]');
foreach ($divNodes as $divNode) {
    $innerHTML = '';
    $children = $divNode->childNodes; 
    foreach ($children as $child) { 
        $innerHTML .= $child->ownerDocument->saveXML($child); 
    }
    echo $innerHTML . "\n"; 
}
```